# Google Directions API + URL Link

Tags: wpf, api, google-maps

I am playing around with Google directions API in WPF. I have found a couple of projects to incorporate the directions into a WPF application, either using a default web browser or the WPF web browser controls.

What I can't seem to get any information on is the following.

Is it possible through the API to get the URL link once the directions are done.

If you open google maps, type in start and end address and click Get Directions, then click on the Link icon top right, it gives you the URL to email or whatever.

Can I programmatically get that URL address?

Any help is appreciated.

Many thanks,

Neill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a list of [URL parameters for Google Maps](http://mapki.com/wiki/Google_Map_Parameters) on the [mapki](http://mapki.com/), you can use that to create a URL for Google Maps.

- [Example (with explanation) from Mike Williams' v2 Google Maps API tutorial](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/basic4.htm)

Comment: Thanks, will have a look at it.